# Load text from INI file

Tags: text, inno-setup

I want to load text from an external INI file to a `TRichEditViewer`, but I don't know how.
Here is my code so far (see CH_toolbar.RTFText):

```
{CH_toolbar}
    CH_toolbar := TRichEditViewer.Create(SPPage);
    CH_toolbar.Parent := SPPage.Surface;
    CH_toolbar.Left := ScaleX(0);
    CH_toolbar.Top := Title.Top + Title.Height + 10 ;
    CH_toolbar.Width := ScaleX(480);
    CH_toolbar.Height := ScaleY(80);
    CH_toolbar.TabOrder := 1;
    CH_toolbar.Font.Name := 'Verdana';
    CH_toolbar.Color := -16777211;
    CH_toolbar.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
    CH_toolbar.RTFText := ExpandConstant(#ReadIni("setupPages", "setupValues", "SPEulatext", "")) ;
```

How do I insert`SPEulatext` value in `CH_toolbar.RTFText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#ReadIni` is executed at compile time so it inserts a very long (unquoted) string literal.

If you want to load it at run time, use the [`GetIniString()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getinistring) function:

```
CH_toolbar.RTFText := GetIniString('setupValues', 'SPEulatext', '', 'setupPages');
```

(`setupPages` is the file name in both cases)

Note that Ini strings have a limited length and can't contain new line characters so an INI file is probably a bad choice for this.

Alternatively, you can load an RTF or text file directly:

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('lgpl-3.0.txt');
LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}/lgpl-3.0.txt'), LGPLText);
LGPLPage.RichEditViewer.RTFText := LGPLText;
```

Comment: 10 x Deanna it helped

Comment: I tried the `GetIniString` it doesn't seems to work,
this is my ini data - `[setupValues]
SPEulatext='cool'`,
I don't see the word "cool" on the page

Comment: Is the path correct to the ini file? You may need to use `ExpandConstants('{src}\LicenceInfo.ini')` or similar as the last parameter to `GetIniString()`. Does the default value show instead?

Comment: I gave the full file path 
(C:\Users\MY NAME\Desktop\InnoSetupTool\setupPages.ini) and it's working, with which const i can shorten this, my ".iss" file is also under "InnoSetupTool" folder

Comment: The one I just gave. [`{src}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm) refers to the folder containing the setup executable itself.

Comment: 10xx Deanna it helped